# plus 1 to integer record for each record in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need plus some value to integer column for many records in db. 
I'm trying to do it in "clean" way:

```
Transaction.where("account_id = ? AND date > ?", t.account_id, t.date).
update_all("account_state = account + ?", account_offset)
```

or

```
Transaction.where("account_id = ? AND date > ?", t.account_id, t.date).
update_all("account_state += ?", account_offset)
```

i get error:

```
QLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: 
UPDATE "transactions" SET account_state = (account_state + ?) 
WHERE (account_id = 1 AND date > '2012-03-01') AND (-10000)
```

But works "dirty" way:

```
Transaction.where("account_id = ? AND date > ?", t.account_id, t.date).
update_all("account_state = account + #{account_offset}")
```

Is there any "clean" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) is not the value of the `?`, but the conditions (optional) of the SQL request.

You may try with

```
Transaction.where("account_id = ? AND date > ?", t.account_id, t.date).update_all(["account_state = account + ?", account_offset])
```